# File exceeds upload_max_filesize, despite max filesize being large enough

Tags: wp-admin, uploads

I am trying to upload a 762KB picture using the multi-file uploader at /wp-admin/media-new.php. This page reports that my maximum upload filesize is 2GB.

However, once the upload progress bar gets to 100%, the upload fails with

> The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in
>   php.ini.

I am aware of how to set my upload_max_filesize and associated variables in php.ini, but that appears to be correct. What else could be causing this?

Other potentially useful information:

- post_max_size is 3G
- max_execution_time is 600
- memory_limit is 256M
- The site is hosted on Dreamhost (shared hosting, unlimited storage).

My .phprc:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2GB
post_max_size = 3G
max_execution_time = 600
memory_limit = 512M
max_input_time = 500
```

Comment: You say the site is on Dreamhost, but you also seem to indicate that you have access to `php.ini`.  Is it Dreamhost shared hosting, or do you have a VPS set up?

Comment: Shared hosting, so it's technically going through .phprc. However, phpinfo() on the page reports all of the above values as I expect.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked my own DH site's settings, and my `upload_max_filesize` is 7M. Lots of room for a 762KB file. Are you low on disk space?

Comment: Nope. More than ample space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a simple typo in my phprc.

`upload_max_filesize` should be `2G`, not `2GB`.

It's interesting that WordPress and PHP/phpinfo() still picked it up and claimed the limit should be 2GB, though it makes perfect sense as to why uploads weren't working correctly.

Comment: When you can, please accept your answer as the correct one.  That way, if someone else has this problem, they can benefit from your experience.

Comment: Will do! Just need to wait the 2 days.

Comment: Also, I'm glad you got it resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there's an `upload_size_limit` filter in WordPress.  To check what your site's upload limit is set to, add this to your theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'shutdown', 'wpse115322_upload_sizes', 99 );
function wpse115322_upload_sizes() {
    $size = wp_max_upload_size();
    $kb = $size/1024;
    $mb = $size/(1024*1024);
    echo( "$kb KB / $mb MB<br />\n" );
}
```

That'll print your site's actual max file size at the bottom of every page.  If it's less than you anticipated, it could be that a plugin or your theme has set it low.  Try disabling all plugins, then turn them on one by one till you find the culprit.  If it's not a plugin, try switching to a default theme (Twenty Ten/Eleven/Twelve/Thirteen).

#### Reference

[`wp_max_upload_size()`](http://wpseek.com/wp_max_upload_size/) (The filter `upload_size_limit` is mentioned in [the source](http://wpseek.com/wp_max_upload_size/#source))

Comment: I am seeing 2097152 KB / 2048 MB, so it is what I expect (and far above the 762KB size of the file).

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser.  Have you tried disabling plugins?

Comment: I'm going through them right now- so far I have not made any progress.

Comment: Update- disabling all plugins and switching to Twenty Twelve did not solve the issue.

Comment: If you create another WP install in your Dreamhost account, do you have the same problem?  Also, I'm starting to wonder if it's a problem with file/directory permissions.

Comment: A fresh install has the same problem. I've also update my original post with my phprc, in case that helps. However, the fresh install failing makes me wonder if I should start a ticket with Dreamhost support.

Comment: I'd recommend talking to Dreamhost, since it seems you've eliminated WP as the culprit.  Good luck! (I've always had good luck with DH support.)

Comment: Dreamhost support pulls through again- it was a simple typo in my phprc (full explanation below).